# Is there any option to see the list of my questions in the Stack Exchange mobile app?

Tags: support, questions, android-app, ios-app

In the desktop version, we can see our list of questions for a particular site.

I tried to watch all my questions on the mobile app but didn't find any way. Is there any way to see all my questions for a particular Stack Exchange site?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is: just open the list of all questions of that site, type `user:me is:q` in the search bar and you're ready to go. (Of course, this works on the desktop site as well, but you already found an easier way :))

[image]
[image]